# how to fetch value from <select> tag

Tags: javascript

I have a list like

```
<select name="operation" id="operation">
  <option value="1">XXXX</option>
  <option value="2">YYY</option>
  <option value="3">ZZZ</option>
</select>
```

I have to get value "XXXX" if user select an option 1, for 2nd I have to get show "YYYY" and so on. And format should be like in the above means i don't have to change value="1","2","3". I need it in javascript.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can get it by grabbing the `<select>` then getting the `<option>` at the [`.selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Property/selectedIndex), like this:

```
var sel = document.getElementById('operation');
var text = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/fPQfL/).

Answer (score 0):

```
var dropdown = document.getElementById('operation');
var selected = dropdown[dropdown.selectedIndex].text;
```

probably also check for selectedIndex not being out of bounds

Answer (score 0):

Try this to alert selected option's text :

```
<select name="operation" id="operation" 
        onchange="alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);">
  <option value="1">XXXX</option>
  <option value="2">YYY</option>
  <option value="3">ZZZ</option>
</select>
```